# Springsource tool suite does not refresh saved local file after compare with external tool

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I use Springsource tool Suite, and have setup an external diff ("Meld") with SVN when comparing a file.

The problem is that SpringSource Tool Suite does not know when the file in the project has been altered during the compare process, and thus needs a refresh of the file in the project.

If I modify my local file in "Meld" and then save it, STS doesn't know this has happened and I must do a manual refresh by right-clicking the file.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option that you can enable to automatically refresh resources that are changed outside of Eclipse. Please go to: Preferences -> General -> Workspace and enable "Refresh using native hooks or polling".